# Css custom list-style with not aligned vertical position and list-style-type curved arrow

Tags: html, css

I have html structure like this:

```
<div class="details">
 <p class="title">Title</p>
  <ul>
   <li> Test 1 </li>
   <li> Test 2 </li>
   <li> Test 3 </li>
   <li> Test 4 </li>
   <li> Test 5 </li>
   <li> Test 6 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i want to make the list-style not vertical aligned and the title will be in the middle pointing to each list roughly like this:

[image: example]

is there anyway to style it like the image above and keep it responsive?

Comment: Is the number of list items fixed at 6?

Comment: @ovokuro no, the minimum is six and maximum is 9

Comment: Any nested lists?

Comment: @AurelBílý No nested list

Comment: Do you want it randomly arranged every time you open it?

Comment: @vincenth520 no, just normal arranged order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, with images, background-image, SVG graphics, etc etc. Here is a simple, albeit CSS-heavy example.

```css
.details {
  position: relative;
}

.details p {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  margin: -.5em 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.details li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.details li::after {
  content: "▶";
  font-size: 11px;
  left: -8px;
  line-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.details li::before {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 12px;
  left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
}

.details li:nth-child(1)::before,
.details li:nth-child(2)::before,
.details li:nth-child(3)::before {
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  top: 8px;
}

.details li:nth-child(4)::before,
.details li:nth-child(5)::before,
.details li:nth-child(6)::before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 30px;
  bottom: 7px;
}

.details li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25px;
}
.details li:nth-child(2)::before {
  height: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 30px;
}
.details li:nth-child(3)::before {
  height: 7px;
}
.details li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 25px;
}
.details li:nth-child(4)::before {
  height: 7px;
}
.details li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 15px;
}
.details li:nth-child(5)::before {
  height: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `<p>` is centered vertically, although the arrow shapes do not change based on the number of elements. This could still be achieved either with a custom class or some selector magic.

*Edit:* To center the `.details` block horizontally, `text-align` won't work. Here's how to do it:

```css
.details {
  position: relative;
}

.details p {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  margin: -.5em 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right; /**/
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%; /**/
}

.details ul {
  padding-left: 50%; /**/
}

.details li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.details li::after {
  content: "▶";
  font-size: 11px;
  left: -8px;
  line-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.details li::before {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 12px;
  left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
}

.details li:nth-child(1)::before,
.details li:nth-child(2)::before,
.details li:nth-child(3)::before {
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  top: 8px;
}

.details li:nth-child(4)::before,
.details li:nth-child(5)::before,
.details li:nth-child(6)::before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 30px;
  bottom: 7px;
}

.details li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25px;
}
.details li:nth-child(2)::before {
  height: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 30px;
}
.details li:nth-child(3)::before {
  height: 7px;
}
.details li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 25px;
}
.details li:nth-child(4)::before {
  height: 7px;
}
.details li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 15px;
}
.details li:nth-child(5)::before {
  height: 10px;
}
.details li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Most of the CSS is the same, I only added three lines, marked with `/**/`. Hope this helps.

Comment: when i tried to align the content inside the details div by using text-align:center, it becomes messy

Comment: @Hunter How do you want to align it exactly?

Comment: i want to bring all the content to the center, because there's a parent div